# Instancio - Generate past date as string format YYYYMMDD

Tags: java, date, date-formatting, instancio

I'm trying to use Instancio to generate data for testing. The Student class has a birthdate member as a String type to store the date in the format YYYYMMDD.

How can I use **Instancio** library (test data generator) to generate a date in the format yyyyMMdd as string?

Here was my starting poing:

```
Student student = Instancio.of(Student.class)
  .generate(field(Student::getBirthdate), gen -> gen.temporal().localDate().past())
  .create();
```

Thx

Comment: Is there any reason `Student` is using a string to represent a date instead of just `LocalDate`? Is that something you can change?

Comment: Yes, it should be `LocalDate`. What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it's a good practice to declare the field as a`LocalDate` instead of a `String`. If you cannot change that, you can map the date to a string using the `as()` method:

```java
Student student = Instancio.of(Student.class)
  .generate(field(Student::getBirthdate), gen -> gen.temporal().localDate().past().as(dob -> dob.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)))
  .create();
```

Comment: Hi @armandino, thanks for the suggestion. That was exactly what I was searching for! Thx